# Язык C. Длинная арифметика - функция умножения

Tags: c, массивы

Еще раз, заново.
Функция умножения чисел, представленных в виде массива из 10 элементов в 12-ричной системе счисления

```
//Работа с числами в 12-ричной системе счисления
#include <stdio.h>
#define radix 12

//вывод цифры
void PrintDigit(int permissionDigit) {
    char numeralSystem[radix] = "0123456789AB";
    if((permissionDigit>=0)&&(permissionDigit < radix))
        printf("%c", numeralSystem[permissionDigit]);
}

//вывод числа
void PrintNumber(int *permissionNumber) {
    int i;
    for (i=9; i>=0; i--) {
        if((permissionNumber[i] >= 0) && (permissionNumber[i] < radix))
            PrintDigit(permissionNumber[i]);
    }
}

//обнуление массива
void SetToZero (int *array) {
    for (int i; i<=9; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
}

//функция умножение (первый множитель, второй множитель, результат)
void Multiplication (int *multiplier, int *multiplicand, int *result) {
    int i, j,
    carryFlag, VspRez;      //carryFlag - флаг переноса
    SetToZero (result);
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        carryFlag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            VspRez = multiplier[i] * multiplicand[j] + carryFlag + result[i + j];
            result[i + j] = VspRez % 12;
            carryFlag = VspRez / 12;
        }
        result[i+j+1] = carryFlag;
    }
}

int main() {

    int firstNumber[10] = {11,2,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0},  //firstNumber = A22B
    secondNumber[10] = {10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};      //second = A
    int *firstPointer = firstNumber,
    *secondPointer = secondNumber;      //указатели

    PrintNumber(firstPointer);
    printf("\n");
    PrintNumber(secondPointer);

    printf("\n\tMultiplication\n\n");
    int multiResult[100];
    int *multiPoint = multiResult;
    Multiplication(firstPointer, secondPointer, multiPoint);
    PrintNumber(multiPoint); //вывод результата = 047BBA5433

    return 0;
}
```

Результат при выводе:

> `multiPoint = 047BBA5433`

хотя должно быть `85A52`. В чем дело?

Comment: Эээ... А есть ли у вас отладчик?

Comment: почему-то не инициализированная переменная `for (int i;` в `SetToZero`

Comment: Вы же каждый раз затираете предыдущее значение result[i], вам нужно не присваивание, а +=, в строках `result[i+j]+=VspRez % 12;`, также строка `result[i+j+1] += carryFlag;`

Comment: @Komdosh, там выше строчкой как раз это значение используется :)

Comment: @Grundy, опять ты :) Ладно, опять я не прав, проверил всё так работает, только как написали выше в `SetToZero` не инициализирована `i`

Comment: Ох, какая ошибка... Спасибо всем!

Comment: @Komdosh, я слежу за тобой :-D